# what is different between theses two context codes?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, adapter, android-context

I'm using recyclderview in fragment.
What is different between code 1 and code 2?
When i first used code 2 with code 3, it occured an error.

```
@NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()); // code 1

//        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)  context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); // code 2

        context = parent.getContext(); //code 3
        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gallery_item, parent, false);
       
        return new ViewHolder(itemView);
    }
```

ERROR

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.content.Context.getSystemService(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.bstcproject.adapter.GalleryAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(GalleryAdapter.java:43)
        at com.example.bstcproject.adapter.GalleryAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(GalleryAdapter.java:23)
```

I left code 3 and i used code 1 instead of code 2. It worked well.

I think it related to Context. But i don't know what is different between code 1 and code 2.

Don't both code 1 and code 2 have Context?
What is different?

Comment: Why is 3 after 2? Where is the context initiated in 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Android, [LayoutInflater](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater) is used to convert an xml file (`activity_main.xml`, `fragment_login.xml`, `gallery_item.xml`, etc.) into its coressponding [View](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View) object.

> XML file -> LayoutInflater -> View object in Java

To retrieve an instance of `LayoutInflater`, we have several options:

- [LayoutInflater.from(Context)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater#from(android.content.Context))
- [Context.getSystemService(String)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getSystemService(java.lang.String))
- [Activity.getLayoutInflater()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#getLayoutInflater())

Back to your question

**Code 1**

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
```

`parent`: The parent of the current item, in this case, `parent` is the `RecyclerView`

`RecyclerView` is a sub-class of `View` class, each `View` will have its own context, in this case, `getContext()` return the activity where you display the `RecyclerView`.

**Code 2**

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

In Android, when initializing an instance of an Adapter, we usually pass a Context instance via a constructor, like this.

```
class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
    private Context context;
    private List<Data> data;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, List<Data> data) {
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gallery_item, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(itemView);
    }
}
```

In your case, because you do not assign any value to the `context`, that why the compiler throws that error.

**Code 3**

```
context = parent.getContext();
```

In this case, you don't need to pass a `Context` via a constructor, just use the context from `parent`.

```
class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
    private List<Data> data;

    public MyAdapter(List<Data> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        Context context = parent.getContext();
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gallery_item, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(itemView);
    }
}
```

Inside `onBindViewHolder()`, you have 3 options to retrieve an instance of `LayoutInflater`:

```
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    Context context = parent.getContext();

    // Option 1
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

    // Option 2
    LayoutInflater inflater2 = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    // Option 3
    LayoutInflater inflater3 = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
    
    View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gallery_item, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(itemView);
}
```

I always choose option 1 because it's short.

Comment: Thank you so much. I really understood your explaination.
So option 1,2,3 are the same after all?

Comment: Yes, they are all the same.

Answer (score 1):

Code '1' and code '2' is almost the same but native implementation throws an error when inflater wasn't found. We can open `LayoutInfalter.from` method implementation and check it:

```
/**
 * Obtains the LayoutInflater from the given context.
 */
 public static LayoutInflater from(Context context) {
     LayoutInflater LayoutInflater =
             (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
     if (LayoutInflater == null) {
         throw new AssertionError("LayoutInflater not found.");
     }
     return LayoutInflater;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Evidently you need to call this:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)  parent.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

instead of this:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)  context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

As `Context` may not have been initialised before it's first used. It's good practice to keep scope of variables as tight as possible, so if you don't need to store the `Context` from `onCreateViewHolder` in an instance variable, then don't.